# Convert a list of strings to square brackets to json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to update a JSON file with converted list of strings to JSON square brackets "list".

My strings list:

```
var animals = new List<string>() { "bird", "dog" };
```

Using this code:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(animals);

jsonObj["animals"] = serializedObject;

string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(filePath, output);
```

Old JSON file:

```
{
  "animals": ["cat", "fox"]
}
```

The new JSON file should be:

```
{
  "animals": ["bird", "dog"]
}
```

But what i get is:

```
{
 "animals": "[\"bird\", \"dog\"]"
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {animals})` is enough to produce the *string* you want. If you want to storethat list to another object's property, use `thatObject.Animals=animals`. You can use that with dynamic types too, eg `jsonObject.animals=animals`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: `jsonObject.animals=animals` fails with System.ArgumentException: 'Could not determine JSON object type for type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].'

Comment: That's because the *backing store* of that dynamic object is a JObject. Use `jsonObj.animals= new JArray(animals)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `serializedObject` is a string, but you don't need it at all it.

As you don't deserialize to a concrete type, your `jsonObj["animals"]` is just a `JArray`. So you need this:

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
jsonObj["animals"] = JArray.FromObject(animals);
```

Now you can serialize it back through `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

Comment: Works perfectly! just needed to add `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` since i wasn't using it in my project

Comment: @ReaKrakover: Glad that it helped!

Answer (score 0):

If that `jsonObj` was a regular object you could just set the value of the `animals` property. The same would work if it was an ExpandoObject. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)` though generates a Json.Net type whose data must be valid Json.NET types.

You can assing the list contents as a JArray, eg :

```
var animals = new List<string>() { "bird", "dog" };

dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{'moo':1}");

jsonObj.animals= new JArray(animals);
var result=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj);
```

The `result` will be :

```
{"moo":1,"animals":["bird","dog"]}
```

Adding a new property will work only if the file contains a JSON dictionary. If you know that the file will alway contain a dictionary, you can cast the deserialization result to JObject, and add the new property through JObject's indexer :

```
var jsonObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{'moo':1}");
jsonObj["animals"]= new JArray(animals);
```